# Hide Column from Document Set

Tags: document-set, sharepoint-administration

I would like to hide the "Delete Document" column of my content-type "create new word document set", but I cannot do it in the settings because it has a gray background. Does any of you have any idea why it is?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

i search content editor web part with JavaScript code to hide this delete button. someone have template code?